# Modal popup is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a submit button in a form
ex:

```
<div>
<form method = 'POST' action="#">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success myDialog" value="buy now"/>
</form>
</div>
```

I need to show pop-up dialog box when `submit` event is raised. I tried somthing like this

in `html`

`<div class="dialog">hello dialog box</div>`

in `.js` file

```
$( ".myDialog" ).click(function() {
   alert();// alert is working
  $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
       }
   });
});
```

for me the above code is not working even I tried `dialog("open")` but no use, can anyone help me on this.

Comment: do you see any error in console?I wonder if `autoOpen` has to be true there?

Comment: @techie_28 it saying `uncaught typo error: can not read property of 'option' null` when change to `true` no error but pop is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set [`autoOpen` to true](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen):

```
  $(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true, // <-- set to true, which is default
    show: {
      ...
    ...
  });
```

You should also change from a click event on the button to a submit event on the form:

```
$(".myDialog").closest("form").on("submit", function() {
  $(".dialog").dialog({
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
    }
  });
});
```

Alternative you can open it later with:

```
$(".dialog").dialog("open");
```

Comment: it saying `uncaught typo error: can not read property of 'option' null` when change to `true` no error but pop is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$(".myDialog").click(function() {
  $(".dialog").dialog({
    show: {
      effect: "blind"
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode"
    }
  });
});
```

```js
$(".myDialog").click(function() {
  $(".dialog").dialog({
    show: {
      effect: "blind"
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode"
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button class="myDialog">open the dialog</button>
<div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title" style="display: none">hello dialog box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success myDialog" value="buy now"/>
```

Change the type of an input box. Use "button" instead of "submit" and try.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$( ".myDialog" ).click(function() {
  $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
       }
   });
});
```

and change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

```
<input type="buttom" class="btn btn-success myDialog" value="buy now"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code works.Change the input type from submit to button.

```js
$(function() {

$( ".dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
       }
   });
$( ".myDialog" ).click(function(e) {
  
  $(".dialog").dialog('open');
});
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<div>
<form method = 'POST' action="#">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success myDialog" value="buy now"/>
</form>
</div>

<div class="dialog" hidden="hidden">hello dialog box</div>
```